# What's the correct way to organize a set-only property in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin, but I have a lot of experience with Java.

Little background of the question... I have a class with a MutableList property there.

```
    class ModesAdapter(val modes : MutableList<Mode> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModeViewHolder>()
```

And I want to be able to set this propery, but to forbid (or restrict) a get operation. In Java it would be like:

```
class ModesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModeViewHolder>{

   private final List<Mode> modes;   

   public ModesAdapter() {
      modes = new ArrayList<Mode>();
   }   

   public ModesAdapter(List<Mode> modes) {
      this.modes = modes;
   }

   public void updateModes(List<Mode> modes) {
      this.modes.clear();
      this.modes.addAll(modes);
      notifyDatasetChanged();
   }
}
```

---

For Kotlin I have two possible options.

**Option #1.** Use Kotlin provided get/set methods + backing property. In this case I need to override a get method to return immutable list.

```
class ModesAdapter(modes : MutableList<Mode> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModeViewHolder>(){

    private val _modes : MutableList<Mode> = modes

    var modes : List<Mode>
        get() = _modes.toList()
        set(value) {
            _modes.clear()
            _modes.addAll(value)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
}
```

Ideally, I have to remove `get` at all or make it private, but I cannot do this because of visibility of `var modes`. To update modes now I just need to:

```
val modesAdapter = ModesAdapter()
modesAdapter.modes = mutableListOf<Mode>(Mode("Mode 1"))
```

**Option #2.** Just throw away all Kotlin's stuff and use "Java approach".

```
class ModesAdapter(private val modes : MutableList<Mode> = mutableListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModeViewHolder>(){

    fun updateModes(modes : List<Mode>) {
        this.modes.clear()
        this.modes.addAll(modes)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

To access modes in this case I need to:

```
val modesAdapter = ModesAdapter()
modesAdapter.updateModes(mutableListOf<Mode>(Mode("Mode 1")))
```

Maybe the second approach is cleaner and has less lines of code, but the first one looks more "Kotlin-style": we have a property and separate setter/getter for it.

So what's the correct way to achieve the behavior described above from the **ideological** point of view in Kotlin? May be you can suggest your own correct option (it would be nice, by the way).

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I misinterpreted the post. What you want is currently not possible, check the duplicate

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VinceEmigh. Looks like according to that post + documentation, the correct way is to use backing field and restrict modification of the list, but the alternative is to use a suggested "hack".

Comment: I don't think a backing property would work here, as the "wrapper" property would still fall victim to the same issue (you could have the `get` throw an exception, but it'll still exist in your code's API). IMO, you should stick with your `update` behavioral method, possibly make it a bit more descriptive. Then again, I've never been a fan of getter/setter - it's "low level" in my eyes, treating objects like data structures rather than behavioral objects that represent real-world objects, and doesn't describe the actual behavior being performed (*why* is it being "set"?).